# How To get JMS Destination from WMQ

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am consuming a message from wmq using spring integration but i am not able to get JMS Destination in message header. I would want to know the queue name from where the message is consumed. In active mq we will be getting a parameter called JMS Destination where the queue name will be available. Is there a possiblity to find queue name from wmq using spring integration message.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Integration, the `JMSDestination` is mapped to a header named `jms_destination` (`JmsHeaders.DESTINATION`).

See [Mapping Message Headers to/from JMS Message](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-header-mapping)
.

The default mapper is the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper`.

Comment: While am consuming message from Active Mq JMS Destination is having queue name but while consuming from ibm mq it is coming as null